# mulberry fruit shrivels up

Tags: mulberry

hi my mulberry tree bears lots of fruit but the fruit shrivels up before it ripens. 
i don't know how old the tree is but i'll guess OLD. never cared for until my sister bought this property 6-7 years ago and i didn't pay attention to it (or know it was a mulberry) until 3 years ago, except to free it from vines that i think nearly killed it. it looks pretty healthy now. i don't know what kind of mulberry it is. i've seen fruit that looks like white mulberries then i'm gone for a week or 2 and they're all very dark and shriveled. it's next to a lawn but the lawn doesn't get fertilized. i did throw some composted chicken manure around it early this spring. it gets full sun from morning 'till mid-late afternoon then bigger trees shade it.
            Thanks for any insight you might give me.
         R

Comment: What was the weather like in your area this season?